# MySQL problem in the sorting of column set as varchar(255)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, varchar

I've problem to order the field `sID_contents_p` set to `VARCHAR (255)` form the table `ttt` stored an a database `MySql version 8.0.17`

This is the result on **[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2riT5SPF35sfryWBN3zfz/0)**, which offers MySQL 8

I need this return, for example when `sID_contents_p` contains 1

```
+----------------+-----+
| sID_contents_p | sID |
+----------------+-----+
| 1.1            |   1 |
| 1.2            |   2 |
| 1.3            |   3 |
| 1.4            |   4 |
| 1.5            |   5 |
| 1.6            |   6 |
| 1.7            |   7 |
| 1.8            |   8 |
| 1.9            |   9 |
| 1.10           |  10 |
| 1.11           |  11 |
| 1.12           |  12 |
| 1.13           |  13 |
| 1.14           |  14 |
| 1.15           |  15 |
| 1.16           |  16 |
| 1.17           |  17 |
| 1.18           |  18 |
| 1.19           |  19 |
| 1.20           |  89 |
+----------------+-----+
```

I've tried this query but the return not what you want (*see above*)....

```
mysql> SELECT
    sID_contents_p,
    sID
FROM
    `ttt` WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(sID_contents_p,".",1) = 1
ORDER BY
    sID_contents_p ASC;
+----------------+-----+
| sID_contents_p | sID |
+----------------+-----+
| 1.1            |   1 |
| 1.10           |  10 |
| 1.11           |  11 |
| 1.12           |  12 |
| 1.13           |  13 |
| 1.14           |  14 |
| 1.15           |  15 |
| 1.16           |  16 |
| 1.17           |  17 |
| 1.18           |  18 |
| 1.19           |  19 |
| 1.2            |   2 |
| 1.20           |  89 |
| 1.3            |   3 |
| 1.4            |   4 |
| 1.5            |   5 |
| 1.6            |   6 |
| 1.7            |   7 |
| 1.8            |   8 |
| 1.9            |   9 |
+----------------+-----+
20 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: That column is sorting exactly as it should, because you've inappropriately used a string to hold a numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the ordering.  You have a string.  One method is to order by the length first:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(sID_contents_p), sID_contents_p
```

EDIT:

If the first component can also vary in length, then split the values and convert to ints:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(sID_contents_p, '.', 1) + 0,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(sID_contents_p, '.', -1) + 0
```

Comment: Note that if the goal is sort by the first number followed by the second, then this approach may not work, [see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7410026d34037a216d2b8b568d7e8563).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . That is a good point.  I added an alternative.

Comment: LOL [so did I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147322/mysql-sorting-column-set-as-varchar255/67147382#67147382) ... it seems the OP reasked today haha.