# MySQL sorting column set as varchar(255)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, varchar

I've problem to order the field `sID_contents_p` set to `VARCHAR (255)` form the `table ttt` stored an a database `MySql version 8.0.17`

This is the result on **[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2riT5SPF35sfryWBN3zfz/0)**, which offers `MySQL 8`

I need this return, for example when `sID_contents_p` contains 1

```
+----------------+-----+
| sID_contents_p | sID |
+----------------+-----+
| 1.1            |   1 |
| 1.2            |   2 |
| 1.3            |   3 |
| 1.4            |   4 |
| 1.5            |   5 |
| 1.6            |   6 |
| 1.7            |   7 |
| 1.8            |   8 |
| 1.9            |   9 |
| 1.10           |  10 |
| 1.11           |  11 |
| 1.12           |  12 |
| 1.13           |  13 |
| 1.14           |  14 |
| 1.15           |  15 |
| 1.16           |  16 |
| 1.17           |  17 |
| 1.18           |  18 |
| 1.19           |  19 |
| 1.20           |  89 |
+----------------+-----+
```

I've tried this query, using this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql), -**please this question is not a duplicate because the suggestion doesn't work in my case-**, but the return not what you want *(see above)*....

```
mysql> SELECT
    sID_contents_p,
    sID 
FROM
    `ttt` 
ORDER BY
    LENGTH( sID_contents_p ),
    sID_contents_p;
+----------------+-----+
| sID_contents_p | sID |
+----------------+-----+
| 1.1            |   1 |
| 1.2            |   2 |
| 1.3            |   3 |
| 1.4            |   4 |
| 1.5            |   5 |
| 1.6            |   6 |
| 1.7            |   7 |
| 1.8            |   8 |
| 1.9            |   9 |
| 2.1            |  20 |
| 2.2            |  21 |
| 2.3            |  22 |
| 2.4            |  23 |
| 2.5            |  24 |
| 2.6            |  25 |
| 2.7            |  26 |
| 2.8            |  27 |
| 2.9            |  28 |
| 3.1            |  31 |
| 3.2            |  32 |
| 3.3            |  33 |
| 3.4            |  34 |
| 3.5            |  35 |
| 3.6            |  36 |
| 3.7            |  37 |
| 3.8            |  38 |
| 3.9            |  39 |
| 4.1            |  40 |
| 4.2            |  41 |
| 5.1            |  42 |
| 5.2            |  43 |
| 5.3            |  44 |
| 5.4            |  45 |
| 5.5            |  46 |
| 5.6            |  47 |
| 5.7            |  48 |
| 5.8            |  49 |
| 5.9            |  50 |
| 6.1            |  55 |
| 6.2            |  56 |
| 6.3            |  57 |
| 6.4            |  58 |
| 6.5            |  59 |
| 6.6            |  60 |
| 6.7            |  61 |
| 6.8            |  62 |
| 6.9            |  63 |
| 7.1            |  66 |
| 7.2            |  67 |
| 7.3            |  68 |
| 7.4            |  69 |
| 7.5            |  70 |
| 7.6            |  71 |
| 7.7            |  72 |
| 7.8            |  73 |
| 7.9            |  74 |
| 8.1            |  84 |
| 8.2            |  85 |
| 8.3            |  86 |
| 8.4            |  87 |
| 8.5            |  88 |
| 1.10           |  10 |
| 1.11           |  11 |
| 1.12           |  12 |
| 1.13           |  13 |
| 1.14           |  14 |
| 1.15           |  15 |
| 1.16           |  16 |
| 1.17           |  17 |
| 1.18           |  18 |
| 1.19           |  19 |
| 1.20           |  89 |
| 2.10           |  29 |
| 2.11           |  30 |
| 2.12           |  90 |
| 5.10           |  51 |
| 5.11           |  52 |
| 5.12           |  53 |
| 5.13           |  54 |
| 6.10           |  64 |
| 6.11           |  65 |
| 7.10           |  75 |
| 7.11           |  76 |
| 7.12           |  77 |
| 7.13           |  78 |
| 7.14           |  79 |
| 7.15           |  80 |
| 7.16           |  81 |
| 7.17           |  82 |
| 7.18           |  83 |
+----------------+-----+
90 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

**Solution update**

**[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hDTsxELeMAXuQcNynbvur/0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here with integer casts on the major/minor portions of the SID contents:

```sql
SELECT sID_contents_p, sID 
FROM ttt
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sID_contents_p, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),   -- major portion
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sID_contents_p, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED);  -- minor portion
```